# how to remove this error in laravel middleware?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to using middleware in laravel but it is giving this error
"The page isn’t redirecting properly"

i have done this

```
IsAdmin(middleware)
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $user=Auth::user();
        if($user->isAdmin())
        {
           return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

admin controller
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('IsAdmin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return "You are an administrator because you are seeing this page";
    }
}
User Model
 public function isAdmin()
    {
        if($this->role->name=='administrator')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
web.php
Route::get('/admin','AdminController@index');
```

"The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: Did you register your middleware in app.php?

Comment: yes i did in kernel.php protected $routeMiddleware = [
         'role'=>\App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
        'IsAdmin'=>\App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
    ];

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `return $next($request);` to `return redirect()->back();`, it might be infinite redirect loop, because you are still trying to access the same route even if middleware fails.